# run Mysql and Wordpress on Docker, got message Error establishing a database connection

Tags: docker

I am a newbie for Docker, I run the command below on terminal

```
docker run --name mysql-cont -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=qwerty -d mysql

docker run --name wp-cont --link mysql-cont:mysql -p 8080:80 -d wordpress
```

if I access

```
127.0.0.1:8080
```

or

```
localhost:8080
```

it displays

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

It looks like the configure file for mysql does not work well

I searched file docker-compose.yml docker-compose.ymal

but can not get them

Your comment welcome

Comment: can yous show your MySQL connection string?

Comment: I used the Mysql in Docker , so the command is 'docker run --name wp-cont --link mysql-cont:mysql -p 8080:80 -d wordpress'

Comment: I mean how you make a connection with MySQL inside WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you didn't pass database connection string  to Wordpress container as shown [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/).

If you need `docker-compose.yml` file you can use this [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) to help you to implement your project.

Comment: I used third party's document, the official document works, now everything is Ok